# Why is the loop overwriting the initial code, and not creating a new XSSFSheet?

Tags: java, apache, loops, stream

I would like to create a loop to add new Sheets to a Workbook, but the below code does not work.

It creates a new Sheet, but just overwrites the first Sheet instead of adding a new one.

I thought it might have something to do with the fileOut stream, but adding `fileOut.close()` to the end did not resolve the problem.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String response; 
    XSSFWorkbook workbook; 
    do
    {
        // prompts user to pick file 
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); 
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\AMDX12\\Desktop"));
        fc.setDialogTitle("Choose File");
        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile(); 

        // gets questionPacketNumber from user 
        System.out.println("Enter the number of the question packet: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); 
        String questionPacketNum = keyboard.nextLine(); 

        // creates new Workbook and a new Sheet
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(questionPacketNum); 

        // loops code
        System.out.println("would you like to do this again?");
        response = keyboard.nextLine(); 

        // saves workbook
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream (new File ("c:\\Users\\Student\\newFile.xlsx")); 
        workbook.write(fileOut); 
        // fileOut.close();             
    } while (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") == true); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(questionPacketNum);
```

You create a **new** workbook during each loop. Instead; `workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();` should go **in front** of that loop!

In other words: if you want the loop to **add** a sheet; then make sure that your loop doesn't throw away the last workbook with the one sheet you added in the last iteration! And for the record: you **want** to call `close()` on your output stream; but ideally, you simply use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) here.

Beyond that: please read about the *[single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)*. Your poor method is responsible for way too many things. Instead: write **one** method that creates the workbook; one that asks the user for input; one that adds new sheets; and a final one to write the whole thing into a file.

Comment: I followed what you said and it fixed the problem. Thank you for mention of the single responsibility principle.